# Compiled error, declared with attribute error in qcacld-2.0

Tags: android, compilation, linux-kernel, compiler-warnings, xiaomi

```
CC      drivers/staging/qcacld-2.0/CORE/SERVICES/COMMON/adf/adf_nbuf.o
In file included from include/linux/linkage.h:4:0,
                 from include/linux/kernel.h:6,
                 from drivers/staging/qcacld-2.0/CORE/SERVICES/COMMON/adf/adf_nbuf.c:29:
drivers/staging/qcacld-2.0/CORE/SERVICES/COMMON/adf/adf_nbuf.c: In function '__adf_nbuf_validate_skb_cb':
include/linux/compiler.h:347:38: error: call to '__compiletime_assert_1270' declared with attribute error: BUILD_BUG_ON failed: sizeof(struct cvg_nbuf_cb) > FIELD_SIZEOF(struct sk_buff, cb)
  _compiletime_assert(condition, msg, __compiletime_assert_, __LINE__)
                                      ^
include/linux/compiler.h:330:4: note: in definition of macro '__compiletime_assert'
    prefix ## suffix();    \
    ^
include/linux/compiler.h:347:2: note: in expansion of macro '_compiletime_assert'
  _compiletime_assert(condition, msg, __compiletime_assert_, __LINE__)
  ^
include/linux/bug.h:50:37: note: in expansion of macro 'compiletime_assert'
 #define BUILD_BUG_ON_MSG(cond, msg) compiletime_assert(!(cond), msg)
                                     ^
include/linux/bug.h:74:2: note: in expansion of macro 'BUILD_BUG_ON_MSG'
  BUILD_BUG_ON_MSG(condition, "BUILD_BUG_ON failed: " #condition)
  ^
drivers/staging/qcacld-2.0/CORE/SERVICES/COMMON/adf/adf_nbuf.c:1269:2: note: in expansion of macro 'BUILD_BUG_ON'
  BUILD_BUG_ON(sizeof(struct cvg_nbuf_cb) >
  ^
scripts/Makefile.build:308: recipe for target 'drivers/staging/qcacld-2.0/CORE/SERVICES/COMMON/adf/adf_nbuf.o' failed
make[3]: *** [drivers/staging/qcacld-2.0/CORE/SERVICES/COMMON/adf/adf_nbuf.o] Error 1
scripts/Makefile.build:455: recipe for target 'drivers/staging/qcacld-2.0' failed
make[2]: *** [drivers/staging/qcacld-2.0] Error 2
scripts/Makefile.build:455: recipe for target 'drivers/staging' failed
make[1]: *** [drivers/staging] Error 2
Makefile:824: recipe for target 'drivers' failed
make: *** [drivers] Error 2
```

How can I fix it?

- misource
- compiler:GCC4.9
- wlan driver:qcacld-2.0 LA.bf64.1.2.3.rb1.17
- I'm a noob and use google seem can't found some answer

Comment: These errors are about the compiler not finding the headers where these things are declared. Pick one of the errors and find out where it is supposed to be getting these symbols from. I'm not sure anyone here can really help you because this is going to be very specific to your build environment. Certainly, without the CMake file(s) it is impossible to even guess at the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Nuke the python wrapper in your root makefile like this
https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm/+/e7fb62baa7c8b803d7e3b3f3d8bf4e2b916b659d

And nuke Wall and Werror flags from Kbuild of qcacld
https://github.com/DerpGang/msm-3.18/blob/f8b18a46f0da4d3aed84f29eb29f2578884e90d4/drivers/staging/qcacld-2.0/Kbuild#L1009

https://github.com/DerpGang/msm-3.18/blob/f8b18a46f0da4d3aed84f29eb29f2578884e90d4/drivers/staging/qcacld-2.0/Kbuild#L1008

Here we are disabling the compiler flags so the code warnings won't be treated as errors.

Note:-
In case you get segmentation fault after removing python wrapper, check for any residual compiler flags or re add the wraper

Comment: `EXTRA_CFLAGS += -Wno-implicit-function-declaration`
thanks man